# QProcess ProcessState sufficient for Blocked Processes?

Tags: c++, qt, process

I want to know if a process (started with a QProcess class) doesn't respond anymore. For instance, my process is an application that only prints 1 every seconds.

My problem is that I want to know if (for some mystical reason), that process is blocked for a short period of time (more than 1 second, something noticeable by a human).

However, the different states of a QProcess (Not Running, Starting, Running) don't include a "Blocked" state.

I mean blocked as "Don't Answer to the OS" when we got the "Non Responding" message in the Task Manager. Such as when a Windows MMI (like explorer.exe) is blocked and becomes white.

**But :** I want to detect that "Not Responding" state for ANY processes. Not just MMI.

Is there a way to detect such a state ?

Comment: does the process supposed to write data to standard output\error?

Comment: Probably "Blocked" - is platform-dependend state. And it's not present on most Qt's top platforms. Could you explain more exactly, what you mean by "blocked"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt doesn't provide any api for that. You'd need to use platform-specific mechanisms. On some platforms (Windows!), there is no notion of a hung application, merely that of a hung window. You can have one application that has both responsive and unresponsive windows :)

On Windows, you'd enumerate all windows using [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), check if they belong to your process by comparing the pid from [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to `process->pid()`, and finally checking if the window is hung through [`IsHungAppWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

### Caveats

Generally, there's is no such thing as an all-encompassing notion of a "non responding" process.

Suppose you have a web server. What does it mean that it's not responding? It's under heavy load, so it may deny some incoming connections. Is that "non responding" from your perspective? It may be, but there's nothing you can do about it - killing and restarting the process won't fix it. If anything, it will make things worse for the already connected clients.

Suppose you have a process that is blocking on a filesystem read because the particular drive it tries to access is slow, or under heavy load. Does it mean that it's not responding? Will killing and restarting it always fix this? If the process then retries the read from the beginning of the file, it may well make things worse.

Suppose you have a poorly designed process with a GUI. It's doing blocking serial port reads in the GUI thread. The read it's doing takes long time, and the GUI is nonresponsive for several seconds. You kill the process, it restarts and tries that long read again - you've only made things worse.

You have to tread *very carefully* here.

### Solution Ideas

There are multiple approaches to determining what is a "responsive" process. It was already mentioned that processes with a GUI are monitored by the operating system on both Windows and OS X. Thus one can use native APIs that can query whether a window or a process is hung or not. This makes sense for applications that offer a UI, and subject to caveats above.

If the process is providing a service, you may periodically use the service to determine if it's still available, subject to some deadlines. Any elections as to what to do with a "hung" process should take into account CPU and I/O load of the system.

It may be worthwhile to keep a history of the latency of the service's response to the service request. Only "large" changes to the latency should be taken to be an indication of a problem. Suppose you're keeping track of the average latency. One could have set an ultimate deadline to 50x the previous average latency. Missing this deadline, the service is presumed dead and up for forced recycling. An "action flag" deadline may be set to 5-10x the average latency. A human would then be given an option to orderly restart the service. The flag would be automatically removed when latency backs down to, say, 30% below the deadline that triggered the flag.

If you are the developer of the monitored process, then you can invert the monitoring aspect and become a passive watchdog of the monitored process. The monitored process must then periodically, actively "wake" the watchdog to indicate that it's alive. The emission of the wake signal (in generic terms) should be performed in strategic location(s) in the code. Periodic reception of wake "signals" should allow you to reason that the process is still alive. You may have multiple wake signals, tagged with the location in the watched process. Everything depends on how many threads the process has, what is it doing, etc.

Comment: @Xaltar If we're talking about Windows, then the notion of being hung doesn't apply, since to receive messages, you need a window. It may be a hidden window, but you do need one. If you don't have a window, you can't process messages, and you can't be hung since you simply ignore all the messages.

Comment: So, it is not possible to have a "Not Responding" process in the Task Manager if it is NOT containing a window (that would make my question obsolete) ?

Comment: @Xaltar That process may still have a hidden window. Use spy++ to examine the process to check for window handles. If it doesn't have any, then yes, it can't be "not responding".

Comment: That is good. I'm beginning to see things more clearly. Thanks.